# How to traverse between pages while being logged in in selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Let's see the following coding snippet first.

```
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://base.url.com")

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='Username']")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='Password']")
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='login']")
username.send_keys("user")
password.send_keys("pass")
login_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

This portion runs successfully, and lets say the page https://base.url.com/some/path gets loaded on browser.

Then when I try to execute the following line:

```
driver.get("https://base.url.com/another/path")
```

It loses the logged-in session, and I need to log in again.

But, when I execute them in the python console, it does acquire the logged-in session and work as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the second `driver.get` come immediately after the `login_button.send_keys`? If so, I would suspect that you aren't allowing enough time for the login to actually happen and set the cookie in your browser. Try adding a sleep in between the two and see if that makes it work.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the situation exactly. Though I haven't tested it yet.